# Where is the Mellotron on "I Am The Walrus"

Tags: rock, piano, guitar, the-beatles

[image]Wikipedia says The Beatles' 1967 single "I Am The Walrus" Includes the famous mellotron along with it's collage of other instruments such as strings, drums, Tambourine, Electric Piano, Guitars, Bass Guitar, and Horns.

But where is it? How can I hear it in the mix? Can someone give me a timestamp on where I could hear it or make it out?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Am_the_Walrus#Personnel

Comment: Well, there's a belltree at about 2 mins, but I have deep if unconfirmed suspicions that some of the string lines are mellotron. Some of it has George's signature bends of the time, but some of the rising lines towards the end are pretty ropey on timing & have no real articulation. I can find versions with only the band & no overdubs [which surprised me as to how much of that Pianet sound is actually a guitar doubling it], but I can't find a 'halfway stage' that could be 'after strings but before mellotron.'

Comment: Even reading the entire diary of the track from https://www.the-paulmccartney-project.com/session/recording-im-the-walrus/ [& all the relevant linked pages] gave no more clues; the mellotron isn't mentioned.